# Replace date and don't touch time(hour, minute and sec)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table with following daytime:

```
daytime
01-Jan-2015 02:00:00
01-Jan-2015 02:30:00
01-Jan-2015 03:00:00
```

I'd like to update table and replace 01-Jan-2015 to different date and leave time (hour, minute and sec) the same:

```
daytime
23-Feb-2015 02:00:00
23-Feb-2015 02:30:00
23-Feb-2015 03:00:00
```

How I can do that?

thanks,
S

Answer (score 2):

You can add a fixed number of days to the value:

```
select daytime + x
```

Or, if you want diverse datetimes to all go to the same date:

```
select daytime + (date '2015-02-23' - trunc(daytime))
```

Comment: The second version does also take leap years properly into account.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 53 (since it's 53 days if my math is right) to the daytime:

```
update tab
set daytime = daytime + 53
```

Comment: Consider leap years in case of other values.